# Using jQuery Selectors to Create Google Analytics Events

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

So I'm trying to implement some event tracking in Google Analytics. I'm trying to use jQuery selectors to determine when a user clicks a link in my navigation and then create a custom variable that gets pushed to Google Analytics. I can't seem to get it to work -- any ideas?

```
$(function () {
 $('ul.ga-nav li a').click(function () {

     var element = jQuery(this).attr("id");

     if (element == 'menu-item-27561') {
         element = 'nav-home';
     }
         else if (element == 'menu-item-31997') {
                element = 'nav-buickgmc';
            }

              else if (element == 'menu-item-28165') {
                  element = 'nav-used';
              }

                else if (element == 'menu-item-27560') {
                    element = 'nav-service';
                }

                  else if (element == 'menu-item-30679') {
                      element = 'nav-used';
                  }

                    else if (element == 'menu-item-30650') {
                        element = 'nav-finance';
                    }

                      else if (element == 'menu-item-29954') {
                          element = 'nav-contact';
                      }

      _gaq.push(['track_Event', 'Site Usage', 'Navigation', element]);

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by " _can't get it work_ "? Does it throw any error? What is the symptom of failure?

Comment: No error. Just isn't pushing the event to GA

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a semantic error, you have:

```
_gaq.push(['track_Event'....]);
```

when it should be:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'....]);
```

notice the underscore

Comment: Fixed. There's no middle `_`, just a leading one.

Comment: oh yeah, that's definitely it -- thanks. fixed the code, now just waiting for the events to push

Comment: Kyle - looks like this worked, please accept this as the answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will fix your problem, but for sure you can simplify your code to look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.ga-nav li a').click(function(){
        var element = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        var elements = {
            'menu-item-27561': 'nav-home',
            'menu-item-31997': 'nav-buickgmc',
            'menu-item-28165': 'nav-used',
            'menu-item-27560': 'nav-service',
            'menu-item-30679': 'nav-used',
            'menu-item-30650': 'nav-finance',
            'menu-item-29954': 'nav-contact'
        };
        if (element in elements) {
            element = elements[element];
        };
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Usage', 'Navigation', element]);
    });
});
```

Did it help?

Comment: Tried this in conjunction with the semantic error listed below. No dice.

Comment: @KyleSuss: Solve your problem **step-by-step**. My code simplified the process of determining, **whether (and by what value) the value of `id` should be replaced before passing to Google Analytics**. You should definitely use it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the navigation to the next page is happening before the google code completes and so that code gets cancelled.  You could cancel the default action of the link and let javascript handle the navigation to the next page from within the _gaq queue

so the end of your click function would look like this:

```
$('ul.ga-nav li a').click(function () {
    //....your code

    var that = this;
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Usage', 'Navigation', element]);
    _gaq.push(function () { 
        location = $(that).attr('href');
    });
    return false;
});
```